# is null , undefined and false data types in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Are Null, Undefined and false are same in data types in javascript ?

```
if(null){
    //This code won't work
 }

if(false){
   //This code won't work
}

if(undefined){
   //This code won't work
}
```

are they same theoretically ?

Comment: no, they are all different types ([null](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/null), [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/boolean), [undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined))

Comment: `null` is an Object. `false` is a Boolean. `undefined` is of type `undefined`. But they have in common the fact that they are all falsy values. Which means that when they are converted to Booleans (implicitely or explicitely), they translate to `false`, which is why none of your `if` conditions pass. The same would happen to `0`, or an empty String `""`

Answer (score 1):

- Data type of `null` is `object`
- Data type of `false` is `boolean`
- Data type of `undefined` is `undefined`

So they are different.

Answer (score 0):

**Internally, JavaScript sets a value to one of six primitive data types:**

- **Undefined** (a variable with no defined value)
- **Null** (a single null value)
- Boolean (true or **false**)
- Number (this includes Infinity and NaN – not a number!)
- String (textual data)
- Symbol (a unique and immutable primitive new to ES6/2015)
- Everything else is an Object — including arrays.

**Here are the [complete list of JavaScript falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)**
[image: Complete list of JavaScript falsy values]